# Switch window In selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Switching Scenario
i have 3 windows in my application
on click my first window window will open and switching code is working fine here
now current control is on 2nd page(window). In 2nd window there is one more Button which will open 3rd window. I want to switch to 3rd window but don't want to close my 1st or 2nd window. when i am calling that switching method..it's not working
Can i Switch to 3 Windows ...? If i will close 2nd window then switching on 3rd window is happening but here requirement i don't want to close 1st or 2nd window

Below is code which i am using

```
public static void switchWindow() throws InterruptedException{

window = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
Set<String> allWin = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String wh : allWin)
{
driver.switchTo().window(wh);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
}

public static void backtomainWindow()
{
//driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(window);
}
```

I am getting Exception `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for your query -

```
public static WebDriver driver;
public static String strMainWindowHandle;
public static Map<String, String> lstWindowData;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.navigate().to("url");
    strMainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //button 1 (on parent window - window 1)
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button_1")).click();
    switchToLatestWindow();

    //button 2 (on next window - window 2)
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button_2")).click();
    switchToLatestWindow();

    //button 3 (on next window - window 3)
    //Same as above ... and so on...

    //Now to switch back to parent Window
    switchToParentWindow();

    //All spawned windows are still open
    //so if you wish to switch to a specific window "by Title"
    switchToSpecificWindow("WindowTitle");


}

public static void switchToLatestWindow() throws InterruptedException{

    Set<String> setAllWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String windowHandle : setAllWindows)
    {
        if(!windowHandle.equals(strMainWindowHandle) && !lstWindowData.containsValue(windowHandle)){
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            String strTitle = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println(strTitle);
            //map will be useful later...
            lstWindowData.put(strTitle, windowHandle);
        }
    }
}

public static void switchToSpecificWindow(String strWindowTitle) throws InterruptedException {

    String strRequiredHandle = lstWindowData.get(strWindowTitle);
    Set<String> setAllWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for(String windowHandle : setAllWindows){
        if(windowHandle.equals(strRequiredHandle)){
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);        
        }
    }        
}

public static void switchToParentWindow()
{
    driver.switchTo().window(strMainWindowHandle);
}
```